# Cannot deploy with Angular CLI on Github Pages, receive 404

Tags: angularjs, angular, github-pages

I have been trying to get my simple Angular 2 page to load when it is deployed and I haven't been able to reach the page. I keep getting a 404 page not found. I've tried looking at stack overflow solutions but none of them work for me.

My code can be found here https://github.com/cpp6d/website

please let me know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Does the code run locally when using the `github-pages` gem? that's the best debugging environment for Github Pages that I've seen

Comment: I can browse [https://cpp6d.github.io/website/](https://cpp6d.github.io/website/) correctly(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site works fine.

It is live and working [here.](https://cpp6d.github.io/website/)

---

Edit:

Looks like you fixed it with [this commit.](https://github.com/cpp6d/website/commit/5be45e93caa75e5f5574dfac002751c7253ac428)